# MySQL Remove All Words that Match Table Column

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, string, replace

I would like to write a stored proc / function to remove all 'gender' words from a string. I keep all the possible gender words in a table column (gender_aliases.alias). Some sample values:

Men

Mens

Men's

Gentlemen's

An example of a string may be 'men's black t-shirt', and I would like the stored proc to return 'black t-shirt'. Importantly, it MUST respect word boundaries. I.e. if the input string is 'Element' I do NOT want to return 'Elet'.

I have the query to find all matching gender aliases, and I believe it is fast:

```
SELECT alias
FROM gender_aliases
WHERE MATCH (alias) AGAINST (myInputString)
```

However I am having difficulty writing a word-boundary sensitive REPLACE, to remove all the results from the input string.

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regexp_replace user defined function.

Try to use it, but you need to know how to write regex in mysql

[user function fo replacing using regex](https://techras.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/regex-replace-for-mysql/)

UPDATE

Another appoach:

You have trhee variations of gender position in the string

1)genger[space]text

2)text[space]gender[space]text

3)text[space]gender

So you need to add a space at the start and the end of the string.

Like this

```
CONCAT('[space]',text,'[space]')
```

And now you can run replace function with parameter like this:

```
[space]gender[space]
```

For example:

```
UPDATE table
SET field = REPLACE(CONCAT('[space]',text,'[space]'),'[space]genger[space]','');
```

Comment: Does not replace strings, only single characters. 
E.g. can do:
SELECT regex_replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]','','12345teststring');
Cannot do:
SELECT regex_replace('[[:<:]]men[[:>:]]','','Men - Element T-Shirt');

Comment: Should this not work with your edit? Thx

`SELECT REPLACE(CONCAT('[space]','Men - Element T-Shirt','[space]'),'[space]Men[space]',''); `

Comment: No. it's just a description of the algorithm. You need to write a valid query using this approach. But test it with some test string